# Keeping the Value of an Array Outside the method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, while-loop, stringtokenizer

I am trying to keep the values of my array dates from the Unsorted method, so that it can be used to have another return value in a separate method, that being the Sorted method. I know there would be no trouble in this, but when running the program (which is done using a GUI) the array outside of the Unsorted method is only 1 item long, effectively losing all but one of its items.

I have reason to believe that this is because of the line

```
while((line = myFile.readLine()) != null){ ...
```

Because when i try to output the items of the array outside of the while loop in the Sorted function, it also returns only the last item of the array. There is no reason to use split.string here, as I know the Tokenizer will get the job done easily, and the project calls for using the Tokenizer. I would imagine that I could change the way the tokens are added to the array, but I have tried the add function, and it did not work, and when doing so I get "The Method add(String) is undefined for type string"

Here is the example text file(dates.txt):

```
20161001
20080912,20131120,19980927
20020202,hello
20120104
```

These dates are structured  "yearmonthday" all with a length of 8. the hello is added to ensure that we check for the appropriate items in the text file.

Here is the code:

```
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Project1{
    public static TextFileInput myFile;
    public static StringTokenizer myTokens;
    public static String[] dates;
    public static String line;
    public String Unsorted(String date) {
    myFile = new TextFileInput("dates.txt");
    while((line = myFile.readLine()) != null){
        myTokens = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
        dates = new String[myTokens.countTokens()];

        int i=0;
        while (myTokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
            dates[i]=myTokens.nextToken();
            i++;
        }
        // prints any items that are not 8 chars long
        for (int j = 0; j < dates.length; j++){
            if (dates[j].length() < 8){
                System.out.println(dates[j]);
            }
        }
        // I changed the date += String.valueof.dates[i] + "/n"
        // to System.out.println
        for (int n = 0; n < dates.length; n++){
            if (dates[n].length() == 8){
                System.out.println(dates[n]);
            }
        }   
    }
    return date;
}
// I changed the datesort += String.valueof.dates[i] + "/n"
// to System.out.println
public String Sorted(String datesort){
    selectionSort(dates, dates.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){
        if (dates[i].length() == 8){
            System.out.println(dates[i]);
        }
    }
    return datesort;
}

private static void selectionSort(String array[], int length) { 
      for ( int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++ ) { 
         int indexLowest = i; 
         for ( int j = i + 1; j < length; j++ ) 
            if ( array[j].compareTo(array[indexLowest]) < 0) 
               indexLowest = j;
         if ( array[indexLowest] != array[i] ) { 
            String temp = array[indexLowest];
            array[indexLowest] = array[i]; 
            array[i] = temp; 
         }  
      } 
   } 
}
```

The out of this program is :

```
hello
20161001
20080912
20131120
19980927
20020202
20120104
20120104
```

Yet it should be:

```
hello
20161001
20080912
20131120
19980927
20020202
20120104
19980927
20020202
20080912
20120104
20131120
20161001
```

thanks ahead of time, I apologize if I was unclear at all.

Comment: How do you run your code?

Comment: I'm slightly puzzled why you're expecting 12 dates to be printed when your file only has 6.

Comment: Print the dates unsorted first, then print the dates sorted